# Does A が B となる　mean "A becomes B"?

Tags: grammar, particle-と

The sentence in question:
店員さんに話を聞くと、「１０年ほど前から海外のだっこひもが人気となり需要が高まった。

For full context:
https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/web_tokushu/2018_0521.html?utm_int=news_contents_tokushu_004

My attempt at tranlstion:
When we asked the shopowner the story: "Since before about 10 years, the foreign "dakko" cords have become popular and the demand has risen."

Ive encountered the と particle in various uses about which my textbook has never told me anything, and many of them meant something like "make A to B". So this question is just for confirmation that I guessed correctly here :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're right.

AがBとなる means "A becomes B". ～が～**と**なる sounds less colloquial and a bit more formal than ～が～**に**なる.

> 海外のだっこひも**が**人気**となる**
>   Baby slings/carriers from overseas become popular
>   (≂ 海外の抱っこひもが人気になる)

<sub>You can think of 「AをBとする」 as its transitive counterpart: Intransitive 「AがBに/となる」(A becomes B) -- Transitive「AをBに/とする」(make A B; think of A as B)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Apparently `〜になる` and `〜となる` are pretty much equivalent (become ~), but there is a small difference in nuance. If I understood  [this Oshiete! Goo](https://oshiete.goo.ne.jp/qa/3971946.html) answer correctly, `に` is used for natural, obvious results and `と` when the development is sudden or somewhat unexpected. This example was given:

> 「すったもんだの末、結局彼が村長**となった**。」
>
> After an awful fuss, he became the village chief in the end.
>
> 「すんなりと彼が村長**になった**」
>
> He became village chief without much difficulty.